# Moment: Check to see if date was within the last 3 days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to see if any of the dates in an object are within the last 3 days of the current date using moment.

The keys of the object are dates, but I am not sure how to use moment to compare them to the current date.

Edit:  The reason I want to find dates within the last 3 days is to get the number of issues found within that date range.  I think I can do this if I can just get a boolean flag to determine if an object in the store falls within that date range.

Here's a link to a fiddle I made:  http://jsfiddle.net/yx22qqvz/

```
var currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var store = {
    "2015-05-20": {
        "issues": 1 
    },
    "2015-05-18": {
        "issues": 2 
    },
    "2015-05-17": {
        "issues": 3 
    },
    "2015-05-16": {
        "issues": 1 
    }
};

console.log(currentDate, store);

for (var prop in store) {
    if ( store.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
        console.log(prop);  
        console.log( moment().diff(currentDate, 'days') > 3 );   
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about moment, but I think the simplest and most efficient way to achieve that is to read current timestamp with (new Date()).getTime(), substract 3 × 24 × 60 × 60 × 1000 and compare with the same operation (except substraction) over each timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
// keep this as a moment, and use noon to avoid DST issues
var currentDate = moment().startOf('day').hour(12);

... 

      // parse the property at noon also
      var m = moment(prop + "T12:00:00");

      // diff the current date (as a moment), against the specific moment
      console.log(currentDate.diff(m, 'days') > 3);
```

[I've also updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx22qqvz/5/).

In your old code, you were just comparing the current moment (`moment()`) against `currentDate`, which is always going to be 0 days.  You have to parse the property in question to compare that bit of data.

Using noon will avoid the issue where in some time zones and some browsers, midnight of the day of a DST transition gets adjusted back to 23:00 on the previous day.  Since you're working with whole dates, it is safer to explicitly use noon instead of midnight.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you for the advice on timezones as well!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want

```
function some_within_three_days(store) {
    var three_days_ago = moment().subtract(3, 'days');
    function within_three_days(date) { return moment(date) . isAfter(three_days_ago); }
    return Object.keys(store) . some(within_three_days);
}
```

or something similar depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out.  I editted the question with clarification as to why I am trying to find objects in the store that fall within the last 3 days.